# MBP w/ OS X 10.8.3 Performing Quite Slowly Lately

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, memory, performance

My MBP (2.66 GHz i7, 4GB RAM, 500GB HDD) is about two or so years old. It's been running like a champ for most of its life. However, within the past few months, I've noticed a considerable degradation in the speed and responsiveness of the computer as a whole.

I figured this might be a disk problem - so I ran the disk utility and it produced no noticeable improvement after a repair. Then I figured it might be a RAM usage problem - and I monitor and purge my RAM as often as I can (although I've not had to do this in the past). I figured it may be a problem with the system files, so I reinstalled OS X.

After all of that, the computer is still pretty slow. When I have only Chrome and iTunes running (with a handful of non-intensive small programs in addition), the computer will still operate at a snail's pace and use up almost all of its 4GB of RAM.

I'm seemingly out of options to attempt to improve the performance of my computer to the level that it was about a year ago. Any help?

Comment: Do you have a benchmark that you are measuring to determine slowness? Mouse lagging? Writing files slow, launching apps? I've found people that purge RAM and caches actually slow down their Macs in some cases, but let's dig into your specifics before guessing a problem.

Comment: I don't really have any way to quantify it, but the computer will lag when opening programs, switching between programs, etc. It will, at times, not wake up from a sleep (unless I keep trying to wake it up). Trying to play a movie or Netflix is just a lag-fest. And so on and so forth.

Comment: So - if you reboot the Mac and don't open any apps, Netflix alone lags?

Comment: Maybe not too much in the beginning, but after a bit it will inevitably lag. Nothing due to network either - the same issue is present when playing HD video files. I can't exactly restart my computer every few hours.

Comment: Open Console.app and have a look at the logs for anything that looks like it's constantly trying to do something and failing.

Answer (score 3):

One of the first thing Apple technical support will have you do is to create a new user: log out of your current user, log into the new user and see if that helps. Toss a restart in as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the OnyX maintenance tool to speed up your mac.

Download for 10.8 here: http://joel.barriere.pagesperso-orange.fr/dl/108/OnyX.dmg